# Vue 3 add reactivity classes to mount element

Tags: vuejs3

How in Vue 3 add reactivity classes to mount component, like `#app`?

Vue 2 in `App.vue`

```
<div id="app" :class="{ 'nav-open': nav, 'tools-open': tools}">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, so v3 doesn't let you have the top level attributes reactive. You can nest the `div` and control it that way.
Alternatively you can use some vanilla js to find the parent element and toggle classes and kick off the changes with a watch (or computed)

Here is an example that uses `document.getElementById("app").classList`

```js
Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const setAppClass= ()=>{
      if(top.value){
        document.getElementById("app").classList.add("top");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("app").classList.remove("top");
      }
    }
    const nested = Vue.ref(true);
    const top = Vue.ref(true);
    Vue.watch([top], ()=> {
        setAppClass();
    })
    setAppClass();

    return {nested, top};
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
div{
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
.nested{
  border-color: blue;
}
.top{
  border-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.7/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app" >
  <div :class={nested:nested}>
    <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="nested"> nested</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="top"> top</label>
  </div>
</div>
```